# How are RPMs in RHEL Package named?

Tags: rpmbuild, unixodbc, rhel6

I see that the RPM packages are named as below , but then I am confused about how a RPM released with new patch named ?
For e.g

```
 RPM packages typically have file names like foo-1.0-1.i386.rpm. 
 The file name includes the package name (foo), version (1.0), release (1),
 and architecture (i386).
```

Now I have a unix odbc installed on my box whose version is `unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.x86_64` . There was a bug in unixodbc which was resolved in `2.2.14p2-1` so I am wondering which unixodbc rpm should I be looking for

does `2.2.14p2-1` means `unixODBC-2.2.14-21.el6_3.x86_64` or `unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.x86_64` . I know all RPMs created for el6 with this patch and above will have fix but I see the RHEL has just the below three version `unixODBC-2.2.14-12.el6_3.x86_64` , `unixODBC-2.2.14-11.el6_3.x86_64` and `unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6_3.x86_64` in its repo .

Answer (score 0):

The usual convention is "version"-"release" with an optional "dot-plus-distribution" as part of the release. The version matches upstream; the release is changed by the packager (each time they add a patch or rebuild for other reasons). See also https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Packaging:Versioning.

In your example, `2.2.14p2-1` would mean `unixODBC`'s version number is "2.2.14p2" and it is the first time the vendor packaged it. That may or may not be included in `2.2.14-14.el6_3`, the 14th release of "2.2.14" for CentOS 6.3. I say "maybe" because the "p2" of the upstream *could* be indicating a patch that CentOS already applies that the upstream has accepted. Or they just haven't downloaded and built the newest version yet.